# How to make a button change a tab in Objective C Cocoa applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nstabview

In [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992976/105539), I learned how to make a button say hello world in an OSX Cocoa application with Objective C, using XCode 7.

Now how do I make it call my tab view and make it switch a tab programmatically?

See, I'm implementing my interface with hidden tabs and when one clicks a button, it changes the tab. This is for an installer application I'm coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create an outlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) in the AppDelegate and connect it to the tabview.

[Create an action](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014227-CH16-SW1) in the AppDelegate and connect the button to this action. Example (tabView is the outlet):

```
- (IBAction)selectMiddleTabViewItem:(id)sender {
    [self.tabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Phew! Thanks so much for your patience. I just knew that there had to be an easier way than the way I came up with. This worked!